# How to make a horizontal description list?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get it to look like

```
Cups:                                   Dressy: Messy
Sugar and Tee
Good For Kids: Sure
Charity: Yes
LuckStrike: No
```

But I can't get the CSS correct.  I tried using display inline/block combo on the dd/dt tags, but it just got messed up especially if I want the first one, Cups: to have a break in the line.

```
dl {
  width:100%;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

Rest of code: http://jsfiddle.net/eUk2h/3/

Comment: You're floating the `dd` and `dt`... of course the layout's going to be screwed up.

Comment: I was trying to have them line up on one line so reason for the float. Tell me how else to do that.

Comment: Hi @user2103064, can you edit your question with the complete layout (HTML and CSS) please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, have classes to specify the columns eg. `column` and `column1_2` for left column and `column2_2` for right column. Then by default the `<dt>` and `<dd>` would display on their own line using `clear` property. To get things to be on the same line, then use `inline` class name that removes the `clear`.

I stripped down the class names to the minimum to demonstrate:

```
<div>
    <dl class="column column1_2">
        <dt>Cups:</dt>
        <dd>Sugar and Tee</dd>

        <dt>Good for Kids:</dt>
        <dd class="inline">Sure</dd>

        <dt>Charity:</dt>
        <dd class="inline">Yes</dd>

        <dt>LuckStrike:</dt>
        <dd class="inline">No</dd>
    </dl>
    <dl class="column column2_2">
        <dt>Dressy:</dt>
        <dd class="inline">Messy</dd>
    </dl>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
.column {
    float: left;
}
.column1_2,
.column2_2 {
    width: 50%;
}
.column dd {
    clear: both;
    margin: 0;
}
.column dt {
    float: left;
    clear: left;
}
.column .inline {
    clear: none;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

See working example: http://jsfiddle.net/pvkZn/